# Rhino - Is there a way to restore the modified AST to the original one without parsing the code again?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, rhino

I'm implementing a mutation testing tool for JavaScript.
AST is modified and test cases are executed against the modified code.
After running the test cases, I want to restore the modified AST to the original one so that I can repeat the mutation process.
But, I have no idea how to restore it. Any help?

[Rhino API Documentation](http://mozilla.github.io/rhino/javadoc/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Rhino specifically so I don't know if it offers specific help for this.   But in general you can straightforwardly do this yourself, by keeping track of the changes you changes you make, as "anti-changes". This scheme works for any system of ASTs, not just Rhino.

A tree consists of nodes, and relations between a node and its children.

To construct a tree, you can execute commands to create a node, create its children, and link them together.  Surely the Rhino API offers primitive support for this.

To re-construct a tree at a later time, we merely make a list of actions to accomplish based on node construction, and child connection/disconnection.

So imagine the following tree:

```
          1:*
       /      \
     2:+      3:[]
    /  \       /  \
  4:x  5:17  6:a  7:i
```

I've marked the nodes as *n:t* where *n* is a node number and *t* is the node type or literal value.  We will number the children of a node left to right as 1, 2, ...

Now we modify ("mutate") the tree by replacing 2:+ with a new node 8:mod and 5:17 with 9:j.  Our actions to do this are abstractly, in order:

```
    disconnect(2,1);  // disconnect node N from its Mth child
    disconnect(2,2);
    disconnect(1,1);
    delete(2);
    delete(5);
    n1=create(mod); // node 8
    n2=create(j); // node 9
    connect(1,1,n1); // connect node 1 child 1 to n1
    connect(n1,1,4);
    connect(n1,2,n2);
```

We record the inverse actions in reverse order in an (transaction) "undo" list to be processed later:

```
    [ [disconnect,n1,2],
      [disconnect,n1,1],
      [disconnect,1,1],
      [delete,n2],
      [delete,n1],
      [create,n5,17],
      [create,n2,+],
      [connect,1,1,n2],
      [connect,2,2,n5],
      [connect,2,1,4] ]
```

This list can be "executed" by looping through the elements in order and simply doing what the elements say with a trivial interpreter.

And it is easily constructed; for every tree mutation operation, we push a new inverse operation on the front of of the undo list.   We can make this easy by replacing our tree mutation operations by tree-mutate-and-remember-inverse operations, e.g.,

```
      fn disconnect_and_remember_inverse(node,child) {
            push(undo_list,[connect,node,child,nth_child(node,child)]);
            disconnect(node,child);
       }
```

Where a "delete" operation is used, the inverse will have either recreate the corresponding node type, or, if you will *always* restore the tree,
simply NOT delete the node and remember it in the "undo" list:

```
    [ [disconnect,n1,2],
      [disconnect,n1,1],
      [disconnect,1,1],
      [delete,n2],
      [delete,n1],
      // [create,n5,17],
      // [create,n2,+],
      [connect,1,1,2],
      [connect,2,2,5],
      [connect,2,1,4] ]
```

The place this may get you into trouble are compound tree-smashing operations implemented by Rhino; you obviously want those operations to call these remember_inverse procedures.  That may not be convenient; you'll
have to replicate those procedures with your own equivalents.

Details and subtleties left to the reader.  (I'm not a JavaScript coder either, so forgive any syntax sins I committed).